# send data to email in background

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver

I am working on sending my message data on my email Id.I have made a mainActivity class containing an editText (for emailId) and a Button.
Another class is BroadcastReceiver class in which I retrieve data.
Now I can't understand how to send that data to the provided email in Background.
I have googled a lot but can't get the required response.
Please share the ideas and help me in it.

Comment: u mean u need to sen attachment to email id?

Comment: no need to send attachment.data can be mailed in the form of string also.just need how to send.

Answer (score 8):

I create open source library for this. Usage is very simple:

```
BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
bm.setGmailUserName("yourgmail@gmail.com");
bm.setGmailPassword("yourgmailpassword");
bm.setMailTo("receiver@gmail.com");
bm.setFormSubject("Subject");
bm.setFormBody("Body");
bm.send();
```

With this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

You can download it here:
https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary

Comment: Hi Kris. Can we send attachments through your library?

Comment: @SoH no at the moment

Comment: thumbs up for you. really you have made it so much easy

Comment: @KristijanDrača realyy you made my work easy, even i was not thinking of a simple solution like that...!

Comment: @PirFahimShah I was having hard time with this problem too. So after I solve it, I share it :) I'm happy if I help.

Comment: @KristijanDrača, I found an issue in your library, can't understand why this happens...see it https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

In android, You can send Email with explicit email intent however it will show a email screen and will not allow to send data in background.

To send data in background, you can use **java mail api** to send the mail.

Take a look on this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Answer (score -1):

This is one way of sending emails by using explicit email intent but this will not send in background

```
 Intent sendemai = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendemai.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { toaddress });
 sendemai.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC,
                        new String[] { emailadd }); 
 sendemai.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
 sendemai.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body); 
 // need this to prompts email client only
 sendemai.setType("message/rfc822"); 
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(payment_request,
                        "Select email application"));
```

If you want to send in background then you need to provide some of user secure credentials.[See Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

Comment: sir,I have to send in background.Actually I want to know where should I place this code .

Comment: @Anjali You can't use this code to send in background. This will need user interation

Comment: @Vino you know how to?